# I want to change my icon's color on start menu In UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, startmenu

I want to change My uwp Apppackage's the color of Start menu icon.

for example)

[image: img_comparison]

1's color is light blue, but 2's background color is black.

like that, I want to chnage my uwp app's start menu icon's color to transparent.

I used totally transparent image, but my app's Start menu background color is Blue. Besides, when i drag to make a desktop icon, the image is totally shortened.

like this

[image: ex.img(blue)] (ex: blue image)

[image: ex_desktop_icon] (ex: desktop icon)

So I searched about this, and I found something.

That is I have to make a installer file or edit the visualElements.

But I can't find the way to solve exactly this problem.

Is there any suggestions? if you know anything about this, Please let me know.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but shouldn't you just change your app icon in the assets?

Comment: @Asunez I used transparent image in my Visual Assets, but the transparent wasn't applied. so I deleted original image and change but the problem is same. So I think that app icon image is not involved with this... maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accent color` of your system is blue, that is why you have blue tiles and Start menu icons.

The accent color can be set in Settings, see [Change desktop background and colors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/17144/windows-10-change-desktop-background).

So, if you use non-transparent PNGs in Assets, you have tiles and Start menu icons with solid background colors, like Microsoft Samples and Blend for Visual Studio 2017 in the screen capture you provided.

For the shrunk desktop icon, it is because you have not provided high-resolution PNGS in Assets.

Further read [Icon types, locations, and scale factors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos) on the various icons and scale factors you will need to set.

Comment: Thank you! Even if I change to a high-resolution file and try to use the asset creation function in the visual asset, the same symptom appears and the solution is hard to find. 
On other PCs, uwp application's desktop icon size is enlarged as much as other programs. I wonder if this problem is related to PC.

Comment: Above the Generate button of the assert creation function in VS, there is a tick saying "Apply recommended padding", tick it off, and generate again. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Sorry. Icon Size was related to Windows 10 settings. I changed to a Medium Icons in Windows 10 View settings, and the issue is resolved about shortened image. Thank you for your help so far!